# Set a cookie coming from https on http site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cross-domain

we are trying to create a ajax sign in control on our page. The thing is, that we want it to be secure, so when you are on our homepage, f.e. **http:**//page.com and you want to log in, then the ajax request (using jquery) with your login and password is going to **https:**//page.com/sign-in/ action.

The thing is, that normally we cannot send request like this, because of cross-domain security. On our singnin action we put header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` which value points to our http site url, so it can make a login request.

This works fine, except one really important issue:

Https site returns a sign in user panel that we replace login form with. It also returns a cookie (typical .net authentication cookie). The cookie do not want to settle on our page - I guess that somehow our http page do not want to accept cookie from https action...

When we are on some other https site, and try to login, then it works fine and cookie is set.

**How can we avoid this? How can we allow https action to set cookie on http site?**

This is still the same domain name, just diffrent protocol..

Comment: same domain and different protocol = cross-origin request. Why don't you just make the home page https too?

Comment: I want to have login form on each page in my portal, but still I don't think its reasonable to put https on all of them... Most of them do not need security at all...

Comment: @ŁukaszW.pl There's no reason *not* to just have the whole site be `HTTPS`. The overhead is infinitesimal, and it's much simpler (for cases like this, for example)

Comment: I'm afraid that it might have an impact on SEO + right now it is too big decision to make whole page https because of one control...

Comment: **Don't do this** — if the page containing the form is sent over HTTP then it is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. JavaScript could be injected and the password stolen before it is encrypted by the SSL tunnel. **Serve the entire site over HTTPS whenever anything needs to be secure**

Comment: Okay.. can you give me example scenario of such attack, because I'm not really sure how can it be done?

Comment: Alice loads Bob's page `http://example.com/`, Mallory intercepts the non-secure page and adds her JavaScript, Alice types her password in to the page, Mallory's JavaScript sends the password to Mallory, Bob's JavaScript sends the password to `https://example.com` (this is secure, but the security came too late to stop the password being stolen).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some of users said, it turned out to be an insecure solution. Quentin pointed out that this is vulnarable to man-in-the-middle attack, so the solution is to put whole page on https domain and do not diferenciate the protocol by the type of content.